# Navigation drawer doesn't close when setupWithNavController

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I follow Navigation UI doc.
(https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer) to set up my drawer with navigation UI.

### The problem is, when clicking the device's back button, the drawer still open when it go to the previous page.

#### I want it to close the drawer and consume the event, or if drawer not open go back to previous page.

[image]

Here is my navGraph, where homeFragment contain the drawer layout
[image]

HomeFragment

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <!-- Layout to contain contents of main body of screen (drawer will slide over this) -->
    <LinearLayout
       ...
        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_home"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_content" />
    </LinearLayout>



    <!-- Container for contents of drawer - use NavigationView to make configuration easier -->
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorLightBlue"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorDarkBlue"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
        android:layout_weight="1">
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

HomeFragment.kt  bind the NavigationView (binding.navView) with navGraph nav_content

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // bind the drawer with the navigation graph

        val navHostFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_home) as NavHostFragment
        val navController = navHostFragment.navController
        binding.drawerLayout.nav_view.setupWithNavController(navController)
        binding.navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

nav_content nav Graph, child of homeFragment
[image]

### Summary

I know there is `mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();`
But if I am in one of these child fragment, it would be a pain to find the parent fragment (home fragment) and find layout view and close it. Also how to consume that back event? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use the `OnBackPressedDispatcher` to get the back button event and then use the `mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();` function you already mentioned.

Comment: @AndroidKotlinNoob thank you, I thought of that too, 1. that require me to set OnBackPressedDispatcher  on every fragment inside nav_content nav graph 2. each fragment run into the problem of needing to get the navDrawer instance from its hosting fragment

Comment: If you do it in the Fragments that are inside the navGraph, then yes, that will be required. But you could also do it in the Fragment/Activity that hosts the navGraph.

Comment: I tried setting onBackPressedDispatcher on hosting fragment too. Did not get the event in the child fragment.         `requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this){...} ` set up in home fragment.